# Template Not Found ( path is set the setting.py Templates )

Tags: python, html, django, templates, heroku

Hey I am new to Django and I am almost done with my first project but I am getting a problem when I open my site with Heroku using `heroku open` in the terminal when the site is open I get an error that my base template is missing.

**Settings**

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
```

**any html**

```
{% extends "learning_logs\base.html" %}

 .........
```

**error**

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
learning_logs\base.html

django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /app/templates/learning_logs\base.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /app/learning_logs/templates/learning_logs\base.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /app/users/templates/learning_logs\base.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bootstrap4/templates/learning_logs\base.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/learning_logs\base.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/learning_logs\base.html (Source does not exist)
```

If any other code might help please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out using the \ is the problem i switched to a / and it work if you know why please care to explain it would make my day.

Comment: Looks like Heroku is running on Linux where the path separator is `/`. That's probably the reason. You could use `os.path.sep`  or `os.path.join()` to support Windows *and* Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment yet, so I will mention in reply:

Windows systems use backward slash '\' to denote change in folder/ directory while other systems use forward slash '/'. Heroku has linux servers and will not recognise forward slash